# Modify header cookies for static assets on tomcat and proxied with apache httpd

Tags: java, apache, header, tomcat8, httpd.conf

We have a java servlet based application (very old code base), which is served with tomcat 8 with Apache httpd 2.4.43 and mod_proxy. Application has some static assets (CSS, CS, IMAGES) bundled with the java web application.

I am trying to modify the Header cookie for these assets by adding apache rule, but it seems, may be this is not working as the files are not within apache level ?

```
<FilesMatch ".(js|css)$">
Header edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict"
</FilesMatch>
```

I tried adding the rule, without `FilesMatch` condition and it worked, but that's not what I need.
Any thoughts on how to get this done on Apache level. Here is excerpt from the httpd conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

        DocumentRoot "/apps/httpd/htdocs1"
        ServerName www.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias mydomain.com

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/version$
        RewriteRule ^/.*$             /version.html  [R=301,L]

   
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
      RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]


   <Proxy balancer://${HOSTNAME}-http-cluster>

        Header add Set-Cookie "MYAPP_SESSION=jacplus.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e;path=/;"

              BalancerMember http://myhost-002:31080 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1 retry=1 timeout=240 route=myhost-002
              BalancerMember http://myhost-003:31080 min=1 max=1000 loadfactor=1 retry=1 timeout=240 route=myhost-003


   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / balancer://${HOSTNAME}-http-cluster/ stickysession=MYAPP_SESSION  lbmethod=byrequests
   ProxyPassReverse / balancer://${HOSTNAME}-http-cluster/ stickysession=MYAPP_SESSION

   <Location /balancer-manager>
    SetHandler balancer-manager
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.25.0.0/16
   </Location>
...

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the apache documentation of [mod_header](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_headers.html) :

> Conditionally send MyHeader on the response if and only if header
> MyRequestHeader is present on the request. This is useful for
> constructing headers in response to some client stimulus. Note that
> this example requires the services of the mod_setenvif module.
>
> ```
> SetEnvIf MyRequestHeader myvalue HAVE_MyRequestHeader
> Header set MyHeader "%D %t mytext" env=HAVE_MyRequestHeader
> ```

From the documentation of [rewrite flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html)

> With the [E], or [env] flag, you can set the value of an environment
> variable. Note that some environment variables may be set after the
> rule is run, thus unsetting what you have set. See the Environment
> Variables document for more details on how Environment variables work.

Combining both, you may modify header conditionally when path match a js or css file :

```
RewriteRule ^.*\.(js|css)$ - [E=SET_COOKIE:true]
Header edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict" env=SET_COOKIE
```